# Is there a way to append text to xclip?

Tags: xclip

I need to store data in xclip multiple times - i.e. keep appending more chucks of text to xclip. But it doesn't look like this option is available. Is there a clever hack for this? I want to avoid using temporary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this work?

```bash
(xclip -o; echo "$EXTRA_SOMETHING" ) | xclip -i
```

Comment: This is what I was after, thank you.  But what is the rationale behind this?The brackets must be the key. By the way it work without -i too.

Comment: Brackets are required to make the output of two programs  a single thing.